# Host Adobe Connect on my website

Tags: adobe, adobe-connect, webinar

I'd like to host Adobe Connect's elearning platform on my website. Is it possible? Usually, when we try to create an Adobe Connect elearning platform, it allows us to use the application by creating a subdomain on Adobe. However, I would like entire application to be on our website.

Will it be possible? Thanks in advance.

Imtiaz.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. There are a few possibilities. Adobe Connect is offered in three main modes, the latter two of which would satisfy your stated requirement:

- Hosted/SaaS: This service will be operated on the adobeconnect.com domain and is probably what you've observed already.
- Managed Service: Adobe operates a Connect instance for you. This can be hosted on your own domain.
- Licensed/On-premise: You install & operate Connect on your own infrastructure. This can also be on your own domain.